# PowerShell return to menu after running an option

Tags: powershell, menu

I'm trying to create a menu for tasks i run in 365 Exchange.  I want the script to return to the main menu once rather then ending when i run it.  any guidance would be greatly received

edit - thanks it now loops back to the menu, could you point  me in the direction of displaying a the powershell results before heading back to the main menu.

Comment: [1] PLEASE wrap your code in code formatting markers. there is a how-to link on the page you used to make your Question. ///// [2] the usual way to repeat something is to wrap it in a `while` or `do` loop.

Comment: You have a lot of redundant code in your post which can be optimized for readability and long-term maintenance, as well as settings in your code that do not match menu options. Lastly, you are asking in plain text and that allows unneeded risk. If you don't code to deal with that, then just use the `Get-Credential` cmdlet and parse the username and password.

Answer (score 2):

You should properly format your question, the code is unreadable.

A general approach can be like this:

```
do
{
     Show-Menu 
     $inputChoice = Read-Host "Select your choice"
     switch ($inputChoice)
     {
           '1' {
                clear-host
                write-Host "The output will be shown onscreen"
                get-exomailbox -resultsize 10
                pause
           } '2' {
                write-Host "2"   
           } 'q' {
                return
           }
     }
}
until ($inputChoice -eq 'q')
```

Comment: thanks you very much. thats worked a treat. could you plea point to any documenttion or advice you could share on how i would would display the powershell command running and its results before heading back to the main menu?

Comment: Happy to help. I edited the code, not sure it that's what you mean, though.

Comment: thanks for your assistance.  for example when i run option 2 to add mailbox permissions, id like to to see the power shell command being run in the console before heading back to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment to highlight come suggestions.

I do not have an M365 instance to test this in, so that side is untested, but this is just to give you another take on your use case approach. Ensure you leverage -WhatIf or -Confirm on those cmdlets to make sure of stuff before you really run things.

Output to the screen is the PowerShell default for text. So, I have a standard of only using `Write-*` only when it's absolutely needed. Others have their own
take of course.

I am using `scriptblock` to allow for reusable code to eliminate redundancy. The return to the menu and out of the screen is also in this.

Again, this is just another take on what you've done and what others have noted.

```
Clear-Host
do
{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Drawing,
                            PresentationCore,
                            PresentationFramework,
                            System.Windows.Forms,
                            Microsoft.VisualBasic
                            [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

    $MessageBox = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]

    $UserEmalAddreess = {
        $MessageBox::InputBox(
            'Enter Email Address of identity', 
            'User', 
            $env:UserName
        )
    }

    $UserEmalAddreessAccess = {
        $MessageBox::InputBox(
            'Enter Email Address of person who gains/revokes access', 
            'User', 
            $env:UserName
        )
    }

    $AddMailboxPermission = {
        $AddMailboxPermissionSplat = @{
            Identity        = (& $UserEmalAddreess)    
            InheritanceType = 'All'
            User            = $(& $UserEmalAddreessAccess)
            AccessRight     = 'FullAccess'    
        }
        Add-MailboxPermission @AddMailboxPermissionSplat
    }


    $BannerLine = $(('=') * 16)

    function Show-Menu
    {
        param 
        (
            [string]$Title = '365 Exchange Admin'
        )

        Clear-Host
        "$BannerLine $Title $BannerLine"

        '1: Connect to PS Exchange Online'
        '2: Give Access To MailBox - No AutoMapping'
        '3: Give Access To MailBox - With AutoMapping'
        '4: Get MailBox Permissions'
        '5: Remove MailBox Permissions'
        '6: Create A Shared MailBox'
        '7: Convert To Shared MailBox'
        '8: Get Mailbox Info'
        '9: Set New 365 Password'
        "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
    }
    Show-Menu

    $selection = Read-Host Please make a selection

    switch ($selection)
    {
        '1'
        {
            $MFAExchangeModule = (
                                    (Get-ChildItem -Path $("$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Apps\2.0\") -Filter 'CreateExoPSSession.ps1' -Recurse).FullName | 
                                    Select-Object -Last 1
                                 )
            . $MFAExchangeModule
            Connect-EXOPSSession 
        } 
        '2' 
        {
            & $AddMailboxPermission -Automapping $false | 
            Out-Host
        } 
        '3' 
        {
            & $AddMailboxPermission -Automapping $true | 
            Out-Host
        } 
        '4'
        {
            Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $(& $UserEmalAddreess) | 
            Format-List
        } 
        '5'
        {
            $RemoveMailboxPermission = @{
                Identity        = $(& $UserEmalAddreess)
                User            = $(& $UserEmalAddreessAccess)
                AccessRights    = 'FullAccess'
                InheritanceType = 'All'
            }

            Remove-MailboxPermission @RemoveMailboxPermission | 
            Out-Host

        } 
        '6' 
        {
            New-Mailbox -Name $(& $UserEmalAddreess) -Shared | 
            Out-Host
        } 
        '7' 
        {
            Set-Mailbox $(& $UserEmalAddreess) -Type Shared | 
            Out-Host
        } 
        '8'
        {
            Get-Mailbox -Identity $(& $UserEmalAddreess) | 
            Format-Table Name, RecipientTypeDetails
        } 
        '9'
        {
            $Creds = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:UserName@$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"
            $setMsolUserPasswordSplat = @{
                UserPrincipalName     = $Creds.UserName
                NewPassword           = $Creds.GetNetworkCredential().Password
                ForceChangePassword   = $False
            }

            Set-MsolUserPassword @setMsolUserPasswordSplat | 
            Out-Host
        } 
        'Q' {return}
    }
}
until ($inputChoice -eq 'q')
```

Comment: On a side note, why `scriptblock` (and `.` and `&` for the invocation, and the related considerations on scope) are preferable with respect to functions? Thanks!

Comment: you my friend are an absolute legend. a 1000 thanks yous.

Comment: @mike-langelo, no particular reason, `scriptblock` could just as easily function, the `.`,  I just left that there as that was what the OP already had in the code, and so, no real reason to change it. I was just trying to help with a bit of optimization, to make the code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: @liam-buckley, no worries. We all write a lot of code, yet as a rule, I always got back to look for optimizations/clean-ups, etc.

Comment: as always this community amazes me.  my level is basic and the code will be the long way round and messy! could you point me in the direction some learning material to help become a cleaner coder or is it just a case of keep on keepin' on!?

Comment: hi guys I've edited the original code with your help and have since added a few more  commands.  I'm looking at option 10,11,12 to display the result. I've had a go on option 12.  the command runs successfully I'm just struggling to display a result, it just displays the press enter to continue.  any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't do this... `Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"`, use `Pause`. Ostensibly they do the same thing. Stop processing to wait for a user response. Yet, their purpose is different. one `Read-Host` is really about getting input specifically, the other is just like an `OK button`.  Yet, why put this out to the screen at all? Just log it to a file, by using the `*-Transcript` cmdlets, or `redirecting` to a file or to your own `event log`. Just search for PowerShell logging out and the like.

Comment: @Liam Buckley, remember it is also common courtesy/practice on SO, that if someone provides a response that solves your issue, or gets you where you need to go; you should make that as you accepted answer for the benefit of all who visit SO, who may have the same use case. As for your query regarding optimizations, just do a search for `PowerShell Best Practice` and or `programming best practice` on the web or Youtube.

Comment: @postanote understood and thanks a million